# create and write to a text file (Prolog)

Tags: prolog

I want create a text file (*.txt) and write some string in my text file.

I'm using Prolog language (swi-prolog_5.2.9)

I have this code:

```
main :-
   open(’output.txt’,write,Stream),
   write(Stream,’something’),
   close(Stream).
```

But this code does not work correctly. It creates my text file inside of my pl file, but does write nothing in my file.

Comment: It worked for me (as long as I corrected the single quotes to be ASCII single quotes, not the funky ones in the statement). What's the context?

Comment: and I used ASCII single quotes (like '...' ) too! are you sure you can write in txt file with my code??

Comment: Yep. I ran `swipl`, typed `[user].` and enter, entered your code as-is, and called `main.`. I got a file called "output.txt" with the word "something" in it. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by, "it creates my text file inside my pl file".

Comment: I mean my code can create a text file in my hard disk, but an empty text file! I mean it's not contains 'something' word

Comment: I can't understand what you mean about this sentence: " I ran swipl, typed [user]. and enter, entered your code as-is, and called main."

Comment: are you change my code or not?

Comment: At my command prompt, I ran SWI Prolog (entered the command `swipl` and pressed ENTER to execute it). Then I entered `[user].` to type in code. Then I typed your code (I did not change it). Then I entered `main.` and executed it. I got "output.txt" with "something" in it. Are you on Windows or Linux? I'm thinking in your case, for some reason, the output buffer wasn't flushed before you looked at the file. But importantly, your code is correct.

Comment: I'm using windows. OK. sorry. forget this... thanks for your attention and help. tank you dear friend ;)

Answer (score 1):

Open:-

```
open('output.txt',append,X),
write('Insira o Nome: '),nl,
read(N),nl,
write(X,N),
close(X).
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: can you write in English?

Comment: sounds like wee need some translator in Stackoverflow !